# Verification system. (discordpy)

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so im trying to make a verify system, but im stuck with it. How could i fix it? (The reason for why i dont use simply ctx, is that this is in an on_ready event.)

```
    guild = client.get_guild(id)
    if client.fetch_guild(guild) == '928779004654256239':
        channel = client.get_channel('930910261332819968')
        text = discord.Embed(title="React below to verify.", color=discord.colour.blue())
        moji = await client.send_message(channel, text, embed=text)
        await client.add_reaction(moji, emoji='✔')
    else:
        return
```

> Traceback:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dexton\Dexton.py:19: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.fetch_guild' was never awaited
if client.fetch_guild(guild) == '928779004654256239'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, `fetch_guild` makes an API call and is a coroutine, so any calls to it should be awaited. It also accepts an `int` as a parameter, not a `Guild`, and you probably don't want to be comparing a `Guild` to an `int` either.

However, it seems that you're making unnecessary function calls anyway - you shouldn't need to call `get_guild` or `fetch_guild` at all. Just calling `get_channel` should be enough since the return type will be `None` if your bot account isn't in the guild anyway (as the channel won't be found).

With that in mind, you can change your code as such:

```
channel = client.get_channel(930910261332819968)
text = discord.Embed(title="React below to verify.", color=discord.Colour.blue())
if channel:
    moji = await channel.send(embed=text)
    await moji.add_reaction('✔')
```

A few other improvements were also made in the above code snippet, namely using `TextChannel.send` and `Message.add_reaction` in favor of `Client.send_message` and `Client.add_reaction`, respectively.

You should also keep in mind that a new verification message will be sent each time you run your bot unless you add a mechanism to prevent that. You may also want to use `fetch_channel` rather than `get_channel` to prevent any cache issues.